# How does InertiaJS handle Laravel Response Redirects

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am trying to understand how InertiaJS handles Laravel Redirects using `back()`.

In the InertiaJS docs, this section:

> Redirects

> When making a non-GET Inertia request, via  or manually, be sure to always respond with a proper Inertia response.

> For example, if you're creating a new user, have your "store" endpoint return a redirect back to a standard GET endpoint, such as your user index page.

> Inertia will automatically follow this redirect and update the page accordingly. Here's a simplified example.

For instance, in Laravel, when trying to reset the user password, the user clicks on the "Email Reset Link". This action on the server ends with a `back()->with()`. I've studied this request inside DevTools, and I can see a 302 Response with a Location response header.

It seems Inertia is intercepting this 302 response & requesting the Location specified.

In general, as far as I know, 302 are handled by the Brower, however, in this case, after the 302 requests, I see a GET request sent to the server for the Location with a request header of `'x-inertia': true`.

Is it really InertiaJS handling this or does the browser send a GET request to the URK specified in the Location header and appends all headers from the previous request that caused the 302?

Appreciate your help,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new inertia method `to_route('route.name')`
For some reason, `redirect()->back()->with(data)` routes back to the welcome page.